# Save df as {index - list of all values} dict format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df which of the following format:

```
print(emb_df[['dim_0', 'dim_1']].head(2).to_dict())

{'dim_0': {'A_cj52ruy3z000915s7ab96yaea': 0.021451665, 'A_cj53euj26006zobnofio84p6g': -0.42935920000000005}, 'dim_1': {'A_cj52ruy3z000915s7ab96yaea': -0.09285794, 'A_cj53euj26006zobnofio84p6g': 0.11209411}}
```

I would like to be a `dict` of the following format:

```
{'A_cj52ruy3z000915s7ab96yaea':[0.021451665,-0.09285794],
 'A_cj53euj26006zobnofio84p6g': [-0.42935920000000005, 0.11209411]}
```

Notice that it's a dict that takes my `pandas` df index as keys, and a list of all values of all columns.

I tried all different orients (argument in `to_dict`) None of them seems to fit

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) for transpose and then add `orient='list'` to [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
print(emb_df[['dim_0', 'dim_1']].head(2).T.to_dict(orient='list'))
{'A_cj52ruy3z000915s7ab96yaea': [0.021451665, -0.09285794], 
 'A_cj53euj26006zobnofio84p6g': [-0.42935920000000005, 0.11209411]}
```